# DNSServiceBrowse lists the same service twice, with different interfaceIndex

Tags: c++, bonjour

I register a Bonjour service using

```
DNSServiceRegister(&dnssref, 0, 0, "Fortune Server on my-PC", "_trollfortune._tcp", 0, 0, bigEndianPort, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```

I then browse for it using

```
DNSServiceBrowse(&dnssref, 0, 0, "_trollfortune._tcp", 0, bonjourBrowseReplyCallback, this);
```

My [callback function](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Networking/Reference/DNSServiceDiscovery_CRef/Reference/reference.html#jumpTo_38) is called **twice**, with the same `serviceName`, `regType` and `replyDomain`, only the `interfaceIndex` is different, the first time it's `20`, the second time it is `10000010`. `if_indextoname()` returns `ethernet_12` for both.

At the same time, [Bonjour Browser](http://hobbyistsoftware.com/bonjourBrowser) (a tool I found on the Internet) shows my service listed only once.

Am I calling DNSServiceBrowse with wrong parameters?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. It's really weird because before "something" only one callback it's called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem in my case.

The problem started after installing VMware. It created some virtual network interfaces. After disabling those interfaces the browser only showed one result.

But I think the problem is not related to the browsing. I think the problem is with the flag *kDNSServiceInterfaceIndexAny (0 - 3rd parameter)* send to the function *DNSServiceBrowse* maybe you need to set the interface to a fixed value instead of 0.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that there is a command-line tool called dns-sd that ships with Bonjour, and you can register/browse services with it.

I registered a service using

```
dns-sd -R "Fortune Server on my-PC" _trollfortune._tcp local 1234
```

and browsing for it with the command

```
dns-sd -B _trollfortune._tcp
```

gives me the following output:

```
Browsing for _trollfortune._tcp
Timestamp     A/R     Flags if       Domain                    Service Type              Instance Name
19:48:23.674  Add     3     20       local.                    _trollfortune._tcp.       Fortune Server on my-PC
19:48:23.674  Add     2     10000010 local.                    _trollfortune._tcp.       Fortune Server on my-PC
```

Since the standard tool that comes with Bonjour lists the service twice, I guess this is the normal behavior.